# ncruses mvinch(y,x), weird output

Tags: c++, c++17, ncurses

I will try to explain what I'm experiencing as clear as possible. This is a snippet of code. The ultimate goal is to determine what the next character is in a map for a game, and whether or not there would be a "collision" if an object were to continue in that direction (aka run into a coordinate that is non-whitespace). According to documentation `mvinch(y,x)` should return a character that's in a given coordinate on a plane. What I do not understand is why the output doesn't seem consistent. If I have a blank area in a printed screen (area within `printBoard()` the value ASCII output value is 288. Furthermore, if print an ascii character for a border, it also appears to be 288 in the horizontal direction only. Anything outside of the area for `printBoard()` is the ASCII value for whitespace, which is what I would expect. Is there a way to make this more predictable? Am I using mvinch(x,y) incorrectly?

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include<map>
#include<string>
#include<iostream>

void printBoard();

int main()
{
        char direction = 'w'; //Make this an input.
        initscr();
        scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
        nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);
        cbreak();
        noecho();
        curs_set(0);
        start_color();
        int boardX;
        int boardY;
        boardX = 10; //replace 10 and 5 with in put to the function for a current position of the object. 
        boardY = 5;

        printBoard();
        while(true)
        {
                if(direction == 'w')
                {
                        boardY++;
                }
                else if(direction == 's')
                {
                        boardY--;
                }
                else if(direction == 'd')
                {
                        boardX++;
                }
                else if(direction == 'a')
                {
                        boardX--;
                }
                int check = mvinch(boardY, boardX);
                int check1 = mvinch(20, 20); //<--- values inside board have weird outputs
                int check2 = mvinch(25, 50); //<--- values at boarders are not consistant. 
                int check3 = mvinch(60,60);//<-values outside the board have expected outputs.
                int check4 = mvinch(0,0);
                if(check != 288) //<<---- Trial and error found 288 to be whitespace in ncurses????
                {
                        bool collision = true;
                }
        }
}
void printBoard()
{
        int width = 50;
        int height = 25;

//print topline.
        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
                printw("X");
       }
        printw("\n");
        for(int i=0; i<height-1; i++)
                for(int j =0; j<width; j++)
                {
                        if(j == 0) //Then print a boarder.
                        {
                                printw("X");
                        }
                        else if(j == width -1)
                        {
                                printw("X\n");
                        }
                        else //print whitespace.
                        {
                                printw(" ");
                        }
                }


        for(int i=0; i<width; i++)
        {
                printw("X");

        }
```

Comment: Read the documentation. "If any attributes are set for that position, their values are OR-ed into the value returned".

Comment: I did see that! Although I assumed a white space would not have any attributes. Additionally, it's odd to me that a printed 'X" in one position doesn't represent the same character values as a printed X in another. Could it be artifacts from previous prints (like my main menu that isn't shown on this screen?).

Comment: The documentation says one should bitwise-AND the result with the appropriate mask to retrieve a character. Please consider the possibility that this is not in fact optional. Also please consider the possibility that your calculations of what is on the border might be off by one.

Comment: I'm closing this question. I feel like a dork. Hours upon hours of debugging thinking it was an ncurses issue. You're idea of "maybe I'm off by one" got me started. Being a math major of course I think of the Y-axis as "up." But this is a console... switching my boardY++ and boardY-- fixed the issue.